# how can i change the my color bar is work like a slider in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, colorbar

Here is my code,here i don't want to use slider to change the intervals of 
my plot.Instead of slider i want to use colorbar only,can any one please tell me is there any way to change colorbar  i.e it exactly work like a slider.THank you in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.colors
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
img_data = np.random.rand(50,50)

c_max = 2
img = ax.imshow(img_data, interpolation='nearest')
cb = plt.colorbar(img)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', 0, 50, valfmt=c_max)
def update(val, s=None):
    # _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim(_cmax)
    plt.draw()
s_cmax.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking. How do you expect a colorbar to work like a slider? Where is the slider? What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: actually in my project  we want to change the  intervals of the colorbar according to those values  my plot will change  thats why i am asking this question. is it possible in colorbar?

Comment: It's not too clear what the purpose of the colorbarslider shall be. But you can of course put the line `cb = plt.colorbar(img, cax=ax_cmax, orientation="horizontal")` **below** your slider definition.