# How can I create an interactive Colorbar using Matplolib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

This is my sample code,here i want to create a interactive colorbar.When i clicked colorbar ranges,i want to update my plot. So can anyone please guide me how to create a interactive colorbar uisng with Matplotlib.
Given bellow is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
min0 = 0
max0 = 30000

im = max0 * np.random.random((10,10))
im1 = ax.imshow(im)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'

fig.colorbar(im1)


plt.show()
```

i found this link.It is in MATLAB(second example)but here i don't want to create any sliders, but colorbar i need to create as same in that example i want to move the range values then correspondingly it will update that plot.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/how-can-i-create-an-interactive-colorfunction-using-manipulate

Comment: Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062935/how-to-display-the-all-intervals-in-colorbar-using-matplotlib) of the questioner seems prerequisite to understanding the above.

Comment: Similar questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057845/how-can-i-change-the-my-color-bar-is-work-like-a-slider-in-matplotlib#comment93028205_53057845), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390557/how-to-create-a-animated-colorbar-as-range-slider-using-with-matplotlib)

Comment: hello sir here i don 't want to use extra slider, in my colourbar i have  a 0 to 255 range of colours are there.when i click any range of the colour in colorbar i want to change my plot according to that colour.but you are sending example in that  there are using  other slider max. that max slider is updated the plot but i want to do that in colorbar only. if you knew anything about this can you please help me

Comment: I do know a lot, but the problem is really more that I do not understand the question. So let's assume you have a colorbar and you can click into the colorbar at a certain position x. What is the expected outcome? In how far is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057845/how-can-i-change-the-my-color-bar-is-work-like-a-slider-in-matplotlib#comment93028205_53057845) then not exactly what you need?

Comment: when i click the colorbar position x ,then it will take that position value of the color  according to that my plot will change